# Checked ID more than Child Count in ChipGroup Android when clicked right away

Tags: android, material-components-android, android-chips

I created a Chip dynamically based on a list, and set OnCheckedChangeListener to the ChipGroup. So supposed there is 2 items in the list, the possible `checkedId` should be 1 or 2. But i find weird behavior when i clicked the filter right away on the first item (like in less than 1 second after the screen opened), the checkedId is **3**. But if i wait a bit, like after 1 second, the checkedId will be **1**. Why is this happened? And what is the good way to solve it?

[image]

Code to Add Chip

```
fun ChipGroup.addChip(context: Context, label: String) {
    val chip = context.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_chip, this, false) as Chip
    chip.text = label
    addView(chip)
}
```

Chipgroup code:

```
setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, checkedId ->
    debug { "CheckedId: childCount - $childCount" }
    debug { "CheckedId: checkedId - $checkedId" }
    debug { "CheckedId: checkedIds - $checkedChipIds" }
    val selectedCategory = if (checkedId != View.NO_ID) {
        result.data[checkedId - 1]
    } else null
}
```

ChipGroup XML

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
                android:id="@+id/chipGroupCategories"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:singleSelection="true" />
```

layout_to_be_inflated XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.chip.Chip xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checkable="true"
    android:textAppearance="@style/MyText.SemiBold"
    android:textColor="@color/selector_text_chip_category"
    app:checkedIconEnabled="false"
    app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/selector_background_chip_category"
    app:chipCornerRadius="8dp"
    tools:text="Food" />
```

Comment: You're not setting IDs yourself on those `Chip`s, so `ChipGroup` is creating them with `ViewCompat.generateViewId()`, which is just incrementing a static `AtomicInteger` that's used by the whole process, by default. You don't know what else could be using that same mechanism, so you have no idea what those IDs will/should be by the time your `Chip`s are added. Though this contradicts the exact described behavior, it's the reason that you shouldn't be relying on `ChipGroup`'s generated IDs to begin with, no matter how the specific behavior is happening now. That is, you should set your own IDs.